# Maximum dimensionality of the linear manifold

Tags: linear-algebra, manifolds

What is the maximum dimensionality of the linear manifold spanned by:

```
a) 20 points in a 40 dimensional space
b) 40 points in a 20 dimensional space
c) 20 points in a 20 dimensional space
```

It has been a long time since I took the linear algebra course, so please correct me if I am wrong.

My answers:

```
a) 40
b) 20
c) 20
```

Comment: A simple way to see why your first answer is wrong: to have a 40-dimensional vector space, you need (at least) 40 vectors to form a basis. With 20 points, at best you can have a basis of cardinality 20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum dimension $d$ of the linear manifold $M$ spanned by $m$ points in a $n$-dimensional vector space $V$ is $d=\min(m,n)$.

Indeed, $M$ is a submanifold of $V$, so $d\le n$, and $M$ is spanned by $n$ points, so $d\le m$, hence $d\le \min(m,n)$. Conversely, since $n=\dim V$ there are $n$ linearly independent vectors in $V$; take $\min(m,n)$ of them (and throw in $m-n$ copies of the zero vector if $m>n$) and then take the span to get a $\min(m,n)$-dimensional manifold $M$ spanned by $m$ points, showing that $d\ge \min(m,n)$.

So the answer to each of your questions should be $20$.